# Is there a way to change the text formatter at runtime using the entlib logging application block?

Tags: logging, enterprise-library

I have an application that logs to a rolling text file using the MS enterprise library 4.1 logging application block.

Is it possible to have multiple text formatters and switch between them during runtime?

Comment: Hello Loki. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Sorry, never did - I ended up changing my design completly.  There must be a way to do this.  If you discover anything, please post an answer to this - good luck.